# My cat is sick and I think she might be dying but she is a kitten

Tags: cats, health

She hides in my closet and won't eat. I was able to get her to drink some milk cause my mom said maybe it'll help her because she wouldn't eat peanut butter which has high iron and supposedly milk will help her get more iron. But she barely drinks water.

She has been acting a little strange since I started cleaning my room over spring break cause me and my cousin used to share a room and she refused to help me clean it so I put off cleaning it but now my family is pissed off that it was dirty so I started taking time after school to clean my room and now I'm almost done but now she won't eat at all not even liver or chicken or even sausage she won't even eat her favorite cat food.

I'm worried but I'm 15 and my mom can barely afford the bills and refuses to help me see what's wrong. I've checked her gums but she is an all black cat and I've googled everything I can but I can't tell what's wrong. I'm almost done cleaning the room but I feel like she is dying and I want to know how to stop that.

I'm unable to take her to the vet I wish I could but I'm only 15 and my mom says hell no so please if you have any knowledge about this let me know[image]

Comment: you need to go to the vet now,if your mom dont take the cat to the vet she might be breaking the law,in some places it is ilegal to not help an animal in need,i know i am too emotionaly involved in this but the cat needs help.

Comment: We can't afford to go to the vet.  The only reason she can even pay for me to go to school is because my aunt will loan her money but I'm talking to her and trying to convince her to take her to a clinic a few towns over that supposedly do payment plans.

Comment: @JNSmall we understand that the vet is an extraordinary expense and will do what we can outside of that to help you. If you need advice for fleas and tick remedies, in fact any advice for more homemade remedies to save money, feel free to post more questions. It's great you care so much.

Comment: Have you used any particular cleaning products while cleaning up your room? Some of these things may have made her ill

Comment: No I didn't feel like taking my mom into getting carpet cleaning and that's the only cleaning I'm allowed to use for my room.

Comment: There are veterinarians most places that will see a sick animal free or for a very reduced price. Do an internet search and FIND ONE OF THESE DOCTORS. Be resourceful. Is there any way to earn a little money? You could offer a vet cleaning services or other help in exchange for medical attention for your kitten. This cat NEEDS A VET. Almost any advice you get here is NO SUBSTITUTE AND COULD WORSEN THE KITTEN'S HEALTH. Don't give up until you find help. Good Luck!

Comment: @M.Mat see the comments under the answer I wrote. The kitten was taken to the vet. Remember you're talking to a 15 year old, who has searched the internet and is being resourceful. The child has no choice if the parent can take the pet to the vet unfortunately. :/ So all we can do here is offer support in the meantime.

Answer (score 7):

Stop feeding milk. Cats do not have the enzyme lactase that is needed to digest lactose which is present in cow's milk. This can cause diarrhoea and tummy upsets.

Also, I'd leave off too much peanut butter, keep it for treats or if you need to get your cat to take medicine. It's  a high source of fat, which is not bad in a cat that is not eating, but it's better for your cat to be eating meat. The peanut butter itself may be making your cat feel ill. So try without it and see what happens.

If she hasn't been wormed, she may need to be wormed, as a high worm burden can make kittens and cats ill. It can cause a lack of appetite.

She will also need to be vaccinated if she leaves the house, or comes into contact with other animals. Many of the illnesses common to cats can make them ill also.

[From St Ives Vet (a local vet to me)](http://www.stivesvet.com.au/Kittencare.aspx)

> Cats can be infected with roundworm, hookworm, and tapeworm.  Large worm burdens can make your kitten very ill.  They can also infect people.  When you first obtain your new kitten he/she should be wormed immediately and then again ONE week later.  Your kitten should then be wormed every 2 weeks until it is 12 weeks old and then monthly until it is 6 months old.  Intestinal worms are rarely a problem in adult cats.  The recommendation is to worm adult cats every 3 months. Products such as Milbemax tablets, Revolution topspot and Profender topspot are all effective against all worm types.

It will be important to save to have her desexed or to find some organisation that can do this for free or for cheap, as a pregnant cat and kittens will put more strain on the family budget.

[Also from St Ives Vet](http://www.stivesvet.com.au/Kittencare.aspx)

> Your kitten should be vaccinated at 6-8 weeks of age, 10-12 weeks of age, 14-16 weeks of age, and then annually for life.  We routinely vaccinate kittens against:

If you have missed vaccinations, then two should be sufficient to provide a lasting immunity. As for the annual booster, this may not be necessary for the cat's health, but is for kennelling cats at catteries in many places.

The other thing is to check for parasites. A high flea burden can cause anaemia. Ticks can also make cats very ill and can be fatal, depending on where you are living.

[Regarding ticks](http://www.stivesvet.com.au/Kittencare.aspx):

> they cause loss of appetite, vomiting, difficulty breathing and paralysis starting in the hindlegs.

I congratulate you for taking such good care of your kitten and the time to search and seek help. Please let us know how she gets on.

Comment: Thank you for the information we recently got fleas but they aren't that bad we are almost done getting rid of them. I tried talking to my mom again and I might be weighing her down to let me take her to the vet because there is 1 in the next town over from me that supposedly does payment plans so I figured I could try and convince her of that. I will try and keep you updated on my kitten tho. I don't know how old she is. I've tried but I tried counting to the day she was born and I'm not 100% sure but I think she was born in the second week on of august but I'm going to keep talking to my mom

Comment: So my room is done I got her to drink some water but now she is shaking and my mom is trying to get her to a vet but we have to be recommended to them because they almost free and I used some flea treatment thing that my mom apparently used last time we got fleas that got rid of them so it should work

Comment: @JNSmall thanks for the update, let me know what the vet says. The shaking doesn't sound good. I'm glad she's seeing the vet.

Comment: I read that fleas can cause cats to become anemic well I wrapped her in a blanket and started cuddling her and she quit shaking after a bit. And I got her to eat a tiny bite of chicken and drank more water. My mom is still trying to see when she can take her to the vet turns out the one my mom is thinking of is a two hour drive away but it is worth it and now my mom is willing to do it. She is gonna take her sometime during the week hopefully

Comment: @JNSmall yes fleas can cause anemia, but you'd need a fair amount of them to do that. Check her thoroughly for ticks. They can make animals really ill. If you get a tea tree solution that helps get rid of fleas also. Also she would be due if not already been on heat, so keep her locked inside for that, or she'll get pregnant. If you don't desex her, you'll need to be vigilant with keeping her in whenever she shows signs of coming into season and use kitty litter box. You can use garden dirt if need be to save money on litter products.

Comment: How do I check for ticks??? And I have tea tree oil mixed with argan oil and coconut oil in a spray bottle that I use for my hair. I spray it on the bed sometimes cause it gets rid of both fleas. As far as ik she hasn't gone into hear her and I plan on getting her fixed when I get my birthday money from my grandmother cause there is a clinic who will fix her for 50 bucks near me.

Comment: @JNSmall run your hands all over her including between her paw pads and check for lumps. Then look and see if it's a tick.
You could spray a little of that onto your hands and then rub it through her fur. Where are you?

Comment: I checked she doesn't have any weird bumps besides how her bone is. I'm from Mississippi

Comment: We are taking her to the vet today I'm missing school to go cause when I tried to leave she started freaking out.

Comment: Just got back from the vet turns out she is anemic and she has a respiratory infection. They gave her an antibiotic and gave her some vitimins and gave me some cat food that is pure liquid to give her. And my mom bought some more flea treatment

Comment: @JNSmall so glad you got treatment for her. Please post more questions with adventures of your cats :)

Comment: Glad she made it to the vet.  Be sure to give her all of the antibiotics and make sure she's eating to resolve the anemia.